# Ansible dynamic Value substitution

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I am bit new to Ansible and writing an ansible playbook with template.My template has property as below .

hostname: {{ ansible_fqdn }} --> This is my target machine hostnames

**port: ???**

Port will vary here. For host1 it will be 7800 and for host2 it will be 7801 and so on...

Can someone help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you ports are incremental, you can refer to follow codes.

```
cat template.j2
{% for host in groups['hostnames'] %}
{% if host == ansible_fqdn %}
hostname: {{ host }}
ports: 780{{ loop.index }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

the hostnames is a group for your hostname
and I think there is more beautiful method to archive this, but I hava no time today

Comment: This sounds promising but template.j2 will have all host entry in on host1. Sorry if my question is not much clear here. 

So basically on host1 will have only one entry template.j2 ie. hostname:host1 , port:7800 and on second host template.j2 will have hostname:host2,port:7801... so on...